# How to save normal map texture from Blender?

Tags: normals, texture-baking

Normal map's neutral color has to correspond to #8080FF HEX value. In this case the resulting normal will be exactly the same as the normal of its underlying face. When I made a normal map texture in Blender and imported it into a game engine, I found that at seams I often get strong artifacts, because all my normals got skewed by the texture color offset (my neutral color was BCBCFF)

I am trying to save a normal map from Blender (OS is Ubuntu 15.10) so its neutral color corresponds to 8080FF. Here is what I am doing so far:

- Generate a texture -- Color space 'Raw', 32bit float.
- Bake normal map in Cycles or Blender Internal
- To check that I have #8080FF as neutral -- in the paint mode I select 8080FF color, paint over neutral color region, and I can see the neutral color is identical to #8080FF
- Save image as 16 bit PNG or OpenEXR
- When I check the neutral color in Gimp it shows BCBCFF value

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently what I was missing (Windows or Linux) is to check `Save as Render` box for PNG/OpenEXR. So the following worked for me to generate an external normal map texture:

1. Generate an image in Raw Color Space and with Float Buffer:

   [image]

Note that `Float Buffer` is important, as 8bit dynamic range is not enough for a quality Normal Map. The `Raw` Color Space maps 8080FF as neutral color in Blender

2. Bake a normal map in `Cycles` or `Blender Internal`
3. Save resulting map as 16bit PNG with `Save as Render` checked.

[image]

Comment: Actually I do not think now that 16 bit or 8 bit is a big deal, but getting the correct RGB values obviously is.