# Use scripts to saving baked normal map as 16 bit with correct color?

Tags: scripting, image, texture-baking, normal-map

[image]

This is what my script gives me.  On the left is the regular 8 bit depth image, and on the right is the 16 bit depth image.

The first one was saved using image.save()

The second one was saved using image.save_render("path", "scene") while render output setting was set to 'PNG' and bit-depth to '16'.

However clearly, the 16 bit image is not working as intended.  The color isn't even correct.  When I used it in Substance Painter, it creates similar banding effect the 8 bit depth map gives me.  (while because the color is different, it gives me a bad shading, too)

So I assumed that Blender's render output only adds the bit-depth onto the 8bit depth image to save it, instead of converting from the 32 bit depth image that's internally baked perfectly.

Does anyone know how to correctly output these images in their 16 or 32 bit-depth mode correctly?

The actual problem: When I import the 16 bit version into Substance Painter and added it to a fill layer, it gives me the same Banding artifact as the 8 bit map did. While because of the color isn't correct, it makes the normal map look worse than 8 bit.

Comment: Hey Teacrab, does this answer help? It says you need to tick "Float Buffer" and "save as render" for more than 8 bit output ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51314/how-to-save-normal-map-texture-from-blender

Comment: @Tiles, Sorry for the late reply.  I tried such settings but the color is still incorrect and therefore was not able to be used directly in Substance Painter.  It was correctly the 16bit color depth, but the color always look faded even though in Blender I can look at the pixel value, which they are exactly correct as (0.50000, 0.50000, 1.00000), I took a screenshot of it, the actual visual value of the flat normal, it is(0.73725, 0.73725, 0.97255).  I don't know where is the problem.  Linearization?

Comment: Hey @Teacrab, Hm, i am as clueless as you now. I would report it as a bug then.

Comment: @Tiles, thank you for the effort.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended, but it would be great if BF decides to somehow let the 16 bit PNG have the correct visible color for direct usage inside Substance Painter.